# How can add e2e/cypress tests to Cognito "Forgot Password" flow? (Need verification code in tests)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to create e2e tests with Cypress while developing an app and I'm working on verifying the Cognito authentication. I've got tests created for the sign in process, but now I'm onto the Forgot Password flow and I'm stuck on how to get the verification code.

The only thing I've come across while searching was trying to override the forgotPassword function like this:

```
const customAuthServices = {
  async handleForgotPassword(username: string) {
    console.log("handleForgotPassword.\nusername:", username);
    Auth.forgotPassword(username)
      .then((data) => console.log("data:", data))
      .catch((error) => console.error("error:", error));
  }
};

...etc
return (
  <Authenticator services={customAuthServices} >
    <DefaultHome />
  </Authenticator>
)
```

But this only results in an object like:

```
CodeDeliveryDetails: 
AttributeName: "email"
DeliveryMedium: "EMAIL"
Destination: "c***@u***"
```

Is there any way for me to get the verification code in a way that Cypress can use it so I can test the Reset Password flow?